# No package.json file on NPM start

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I'm getting back this error when I try NPM start on windows after creating a react file.

```
$ npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ronan\desktop\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Ronan\desktop\package.json'
```

---

**Edit:** Heres a pic of my file tree if that helps.

[image]

Comment: are doing npm start command at the root of your project?

Comment: Are you sure, you are executing this in the correct directory? I doubt, that your Desktop is the root directory of your project. And how did you create your "react file" (and what do you mean by "react file", a react project typically consists of multiple files)

Answer (score 0):

To get a react project running, you would have to use a tool called the `Node Package Execute` "`npx`" to kickstart a create-react-app project, see illustration below:

`npx create-react-app your-app-name`

Doing this will generate a small react project with all the directories/files you need to start building your react app,

The directory you should get will look like the below:

```
your-app-name
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    └── serviceWorker.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

running `npm start` inside this directory should kickstart a `localhost:3000` server where you can see a preview of your project in your browser.

Comment: Sorry I was in the wrong folder. But still having trouble with with my robinhood clone:
$ npm start

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Ronan\desktop\robinhood\robinhood\index.js'
npm ERR! robinhood@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`

npm ERR! Failed at the robinhood@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?So how can I re- install these node_modules?Thanks.